# Convert xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have the following xml:

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold" font-style="italic">Some Text Here</fo:block>
```

I need to convert it to the following using xsl:

```
{\b\iSome Text Here\i0\b0\par}
```

So far i managed to select the block element using:

```
<xsl:template match="fo:block">
<xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
<xsl:text>\par}</xsl:text></xsl:template>
```

and i am outputting:`{Some Text Here\par}`

I am struggling with the attributes and inserting it using xsl, can anyone give me an example of selecting those attributes and getting the desired result?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that is easy and generic so that processing for new attributes can be added easily.

Comment: Or, have a look at mine for an even shorter one with no conditional instructions at all.

Comment: @Dusty Roberts: I have added another variant of my solution, which produces results that preserve the lexical order of attributes. @Flynn's solution is really elegant, but destroys this order.

Comment: Given that there's no need to preserve it in this instance, that criticism is unwarranted, especially as my solution's very easy to extend to maintain that order if required.

Comment: @Dusty Roberts: I have modified my second solution that maintains the lexical order of the results -- it borrows the idea from the solution of Flynn1179, but improves it and also significantly simplifies it. Now we have only 3 templates, instead of 5, and no modes at all. And most importantly, the transformation creates results according to the lexical order of the attributes.

Comment: *sigh*.. @Dimitre, READ the question. It's pretty clear \b..\b0 and \i..\i0 are supposed to be nested. Outputting \b\i...\b0\i0 is clearly wrong. If preserving the same order before and after WAS acceptable, my solution would be even simpler, not needing the `<xsl:sort>` at all, and I'm certain you should know that. For once, just accept that someone else had a better solution, it's bound to happen now and then. In your desperation not to be out-done, you've fabricated a requirement that the OP never stated to make your answer to be 'better', and in reality, just made it worse.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Thanks for noticing this -- it was a mistake that is now fixed. Without trying to underestimate the value of your solution, which is based on a good idea, please, accept that somebody may be allowed to have a different understanding from your own about the problem and what is a really good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fairly simple way of doing this generically, using template modes, and the `<xsl:sort>` instruction.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="fo:block">
  <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="prefix" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="suffix">
    <xsl:sort order="descending"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:text>\par}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@font-weight['bold']" mode="prefix">\b</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@font-style['italic']" mode="prefix">\i</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@font-weight['bold']" mode="suffix">\b0</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@font-style['italic']" mode="suffix">\i0</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `<xsl:sort order="descending" />` processes the attributes in reverse order the second time, when the 'suffix' mode is used.

Strictly speaking the `select="node()"` in the middle of the main template is superfluous, but it makes it clearer when reading that only nodes are processed, and not attributes.

You could make it a little easier to add new attributes by replacing the existing `suffix` mode templates with this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*" mode="suffix">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="prefix" />
  <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This just uses the prefix's template, and adds the extra `0` on the end. You can always override it if some attributes can't be handled as generically as this.

Comment: Each attribute has to be generate output twice, so that doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: @flynn1179: Another issue (may not be important to this specific question) is that the output order has no relation to the lexical order of the attributes. Yes, we both know that attribute order is only a lexical property, but all 9 XSLT processors I work with do produce the results of push-style processing of attributes according to their lexical order. And preserving this order in some cases is important to the human reader.

Comment: @Dimitre, it's fairly clear that that's irrelevant in this case. If the lexical order's relevant then it's obviously trivial to add `<xsl:sort select="name()" />` and the same select attribute to the descending sort to achieve this. As a rule, if the ordering is relevant, then it's advisable to explicitly code it as such, to prevent cross-platform inconsistencies anyway.

Comment: @Flynn1179: I actually produced a new order-sensitive solution, borrowing the idea from your solution, but significantly simplifying it -- less templates (only 3 vs 5) and no modes at all. And there is no explicit sequence of `<xsl:apply-templates>` to preserve order, so your recommendation to do so is not actually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="fo:block">
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="@font-weight = 'bold'">\b</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@font-style = 'italic'">\i</xsl:if>

        <xsl:apply-templates />

        <xsl:if test="@font-style = 'italic'">\i0</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@font-weight = 'bold'">\b0</xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>\par}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template/>
```

Also check [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) for further readings on XSLT.

Comment: this is nice thankx, but is'nt there perhaps a way to make the if statement a bit more generic, ie: mayby somw way of looping through the attributes?

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation is more generic and extesnsible**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vAttributesResult">
   <xsl:call-template name="processAttributes"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(substring-before($vAttributesResult, ' '),
           .,
           substring-after($vAttributesResult, ' ')
           )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="processAttributes">
  <xsl:param name="pattrList" select="@*"/>
  <xsl:param name="pResult" select="' '"/>

  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($pattrList)">
       <xsl:value-of select="$pResult"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:variable name="vthisResult">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$pattrList[1]">
         <xsl:with-param name="pResult" select="$pResult"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
       </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:call-template name="processAttributes">
        <xsl:with-param name="pattrList" select="$pattrList[position()>1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pResult" select="$vthisResult"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@font-weight[.='bold']">
  <xsl:param name="pResult"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('\b', $pResult, '\b0')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@font-style[.='italic']">
  <xsl:param name="pResult"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('\i', $pResult, '\i0')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold" font-style="italic"
xmlns:fo="some:fo">Some Text Here</fo:block>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
\i\bSome Text Here\b0\i0
```

**Do note**:

1. You can easily add processing for as many new combinations of attributes/values as necessary -- just add a new template for a new attribute.
2. If order is important, use these templates to process attributes:

--

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
         <xsl:with-param name="pSuff" select="''"/>
         <xsl:sort select="position()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
         <xsl:with-param name="pSuff" select="'0'"/>
         <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <xsl:text>\par}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@font-weight['bold']">
      <xsl:param name="pSuff"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('\b',$pSuff)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@font-style['italic']">
      <xsl:param name="pSuff"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('\i',$pSuff)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transformation borrows the idea fron the answer by @Flynn1169 and significantly simplifies it (only 3 templates instead of t, and no modes) and, most significantly, presents the results according to the lexical order of the attributes.

**In this case the result matches the lexical order of the attributes, not their sorted names**!  :

**If we have this XML document**:

```
    <fo:block font-style="italic" font-weight="bold" 
xmlns:fo="some:fo">Some Text Here</fo:block>
```

**the result now is:**

```
{\i\bSome Text Here\b0\i0\par}
```

**Remark**: While there is nothing as "attribute order" in the XPath data model, all the XSLT processors I am working with (more than 9) in push-style mode produce the results of processing attributes according to their lexical order.